# USB Keyboard/Mouse, Networking broken by kernel update

Tags: networking, usb, kernel, ethernet

I recently (automatically) updated all the kernel-related packages (`linux-image`, `linux-headers` etc) to version 3.13.0-27.50. I'm using the `generic` kernel for AMD64.

After reboot I find that my USB keyboard and mouse don't work. I can't see any USB-related errors in the kernel log, and the devices are correctly recognised, appearing in the output of `lsusb`. They just don't do anything (luckily the box has PS/2 ports which do work). I can still access USB storage.

Networking is a similarly confusing situation. `ifconfig -a` shows the loopback device and a device called `virbr0` which I gather is a virtual device for VMs (presumably because I have Qemu installed). `eth0` is missing. When I plug in a USB WiFi dongle, it's correctly detected by the USB system (as can be seen in the kernel log and output of `lsusb`) but nothing networking-related happens. `dmesg | grep -i eth` produces no output, `dmesg | grep -i net` contains lines saying "registered protocol family N", where N is 16, 2, 1, 10 and 17, and not really much else. And of course no `wlan0` appears. In the output from `lshw`, the description of the network card starts with "*-network UNCLAIMED".

Sorry, I'm reduced to asking this ridiculously open-ended question because I don't really know where to start on this - it sort of looks like bits of the kernel are just.. missing. Is there any chance this is a known issue? Has anyone experienced this? Could anyone suggest anything? In the meantime I'm going to try and build and boot the latest kernel.

---

Some random hardware info:

- Motherboard is Acer WMCP78M, it runs a Phoenix BIOS
- CPU is an AMD Athlon XII [and yes, this is my main machine :( haha ]
- USB controller is NVidia MCP78S, it's OHCI
- The ethernet controller is NVidia MCP77

Comment: Can you downgrade the kernel as a temporary fix?